# PHP SoapClient using WCF service hosted in Windows application on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: php, wcf

This question relates to the requirement to utilize a WCF service hosted in a Windows application on Windows 2008 Server, from PHP scripts which are hosted in IIS 7 on the same server, and from other applications hosted elsewhere.

The application has been developed and tested thoroughly on a Windows 7 machine using Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 4, IIS 7, and various versions of PHP.

On the Windows 7 machine, netsh was used as follows.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:8000/WCFService/ user=machinename\user
```

Various other ports were also successfully added and used during testing.

When the application was copied to the Windows 2008 Server, the essential parts of the application were successfully tested.

The same netsh command was used on Windows 2008 Server, yet localhost was replaced with the server IP and machinename with domain as follows:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://serveripaddress:8000/WCFService/ user=domain\user
```

During attempts to get the PHP SoapClient working, various user="..." options were attempted, including "everyone".

The initial PHP SoapClient script is as follows:

```
try {
  $client = new SoapClient("http://serveripaddress:8000/WCFService/?wsdl");
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(), "\n"; 
  exit();
}
```

During initial testing, the following errors were encountered:

> Warning:
>   SoapClient::SoapClient(http://serveripaddress:8000/WCFService/?wsdl)
>   [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sites\www.myurl.com\WCF-Test.php on line 7
>
> Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity
>   "http://serveripaddress:8000/WCFService/?wsdl" in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sites\www.myurl.com\WCF-Test.php on line 7
>
> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://serveripaddress:8000/WCFService/?wsdl' : failed to load
>   external entity "http://serveripaddress:8000/WCFService/?wsdl"

After some fiddling around the error reduced to the following:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://serveripaddress:8000/WCFService/?wsdl' : failed to load
>   external entity "http://serveripaddress:8000/WCFService/?wsdl"

I then extracted the wsdl into a file and used the following PHP script:

```
try {
  $client = new SoapClient("wsdl\wcf-wsdl.wsdl");
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(), "\n"; 
  exit();
}
```

The error then changed slightly to the following:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from
>   'http://serveripaddress:8000/WCFService/?xsd=xsd0'

I am of the opinion that the issue at hand relates to the "visibility" of the service, to the client, and possibly permissions.

After reading dozens of posts, I still have not been able to find a solution to this issue.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the WCF Service is something you are hosting for it to be accessed by php clients you need to have a flat wsdl. On how to generate Flat Wsdl follow the below link:

[How to flatten your wsdl](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html)

The same feature would be avaiable in the framework as part of .NET 4.5. Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thank you for your answer. I certainly will take a good look at the posts at the link you've provided.

Comment: I meant to add that I have the solution working perfectly in the dev system under Windows 7, using essentially the same wsdl. I am not sure whether this makes a difference re the flat wsdl.

Comment: For your service to be interoperable the best thing is to have flat wsdl. Within your dev environment you might have access to the server to download the xsd at the said locations ? xsd=xsd1 etc,  but imagine for an external client trying to access a resource on your server .. .svc?xsd=xsd1. The firewall on your server might not allow access to that resource.

Comment: Rajesh, this certainly helped me to get past the SoapClient creation errors, many thanks. It appears to confirm that the issues relate to the wsdl and wcf configuration rather than access issues, so there is light at the end of this tunnel.

Comment: At present I am experiencing errors during the method calls. This service was originally built using the default interface generated when adding a new service library, hence the call to GetData. One of the errors which indicates configuration problems is the following.Caught exception: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetData'. 
OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. 
Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'GetData' and namespace ''. 
Found node type 'Element' with name 'parameters' and namespace ''

Comment: Its to do with your request body not being the format that WCF expects. Just make sure that the request body being sent to the service is proper. You can use fiddler to capture the request body from your client

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thank you for your response. It is apparent that I should implement a wsdl flattening solution. I have tried FlatWsdl, but it gives me an unhandled ArgumentException in FlatWsdlServiceHost when base.ApplyConfiguration() is called and gives a message starting with 
This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  
There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. 
If your service is being hosted in IIS... I am currently hosting the service in a Windows application, and have not been able to determine what is causing this. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your configuration for the service.

Comment: The <baseAddresses> element in the config file was causing the conflict. I have implemented FlatWsdl, this appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are working with a .NET WCF service you can just change the location you download the wsdl from .svc?wsdl to .svc?singleWsdl and the WCF server will take care of the recursion / linking work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This may the answer,.net has the default config make this error.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47761

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.